# Scatter Plot with Colobar

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I am trying to plot some more complex data but for the sake of example, I have simplified to show what I am trying to do but is not working. See the below code and output image. Notice I have a section commented out. I essentially want to plot the commented section on top but I get an error:

ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "0.0"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "0.0"
cannot convert argument to rgb sequence

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

x1=[1.0,1.5,2.2,1.8]
y1=[1.1,1.4,2.0,1.75]

x2=[1.5,2.5,3.0,3.5,3.6]
y2=[1.3,2.2,3.3,3.4,3.5]

height=[0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax=plt.subplot()
divider=make_axes_locatable(ax)
sc=plt.scatter(x2, y2, c=height, vmin=np.min(height)-0.5,
           vmax=np.max(height)+0.5, marker='o', s=40, 
           cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', len(height)))

#sc=plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=height, vmin=np.min(height)-0.5,
#               vmax=np.max(height)+0.5, marker='o', s=40, 
#               cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', len(height)))

cax=divider.append_axes("right", size='5%', pad=0.05)
cbar=plt.colorbar(sc, cax=cax, ticks=np.arange(np.min(height),np.max(height)+1,1.0))
```

I do have some sort of an idea of the error. Because the second set of data does not share the same length as the first or vise versa, the color coding gets confused. Is there a way to do something like this?

[image: A simple plot from above code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `c` argument of `scatter` expects either a single color specifier (e.g. `'blue'`) or a series of color specifiers (e.g. `['blue', 'red', ...]`) or a series of numbers that are mapped using the colormap (e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, ...]`, as you used it here).

However, in your commented-out case, the series you provide is not matchable to your data, so `scatter` doesn't know what to do with it. What do you want to do with it?

You might e.g. try

```
height1 = np.arange(len(x1))
sc=plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=height1, vmin=np.min(height1)-0.5,
               vmax=np.max(height1)+0.5, marker='o', s=40, 
               cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', len(height)))
```

**Edit**: The way this works is as follows: Every data point (x, y) is associated with an element in c, that is `c[i]` is assigned to the marker at `(x[i], y[i])`. This is why `c`, `x` and `y` all have to have the same length, otherwise the matching doesn't work. `NaN` values in c will not help here. However, your values in `c` are only converted to colors using the colormap you specififed. And the range of the colormap is determined by `vmin` and `vmax`. So, to make sure your color use the same data range for all your data sets, just precompute `vmin` and `vmax` prior to plotting using all data and set it accordingly.

So in your case:

```
h1 = np.arange(len(x1))
h2 = np.arange(len(x2))

minval = min([np.min(h) for h in [h1, h2]])
maxval = max([np.max(h) for h in [h1, h2]])
nh = len(np.arange(minval, maxval+1, 1))
```

and then

```
sc=plt.scatter(x1, y1, c=h1, marker='o', s=40, 
               vmin=minval-0.5, vmax=maxval+0.5, 
               cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', nh)
          )
```

and for the colorbar

```
cbar=plt.colorbar(sc, cax=cax, ticks=np.arange(minval, maxval+1,1.0))
```

Comment: I see how this can work and I tried this now and it works. Problem is in my dataset, I am not sure the size of my x1(s) as I will have many but the colorbar and the map needs to be same for all datasets that are mapped and plotted. For example, c argument needs to stay constant and map the colors to the dataset regardless of the size of the dataset. Is there a way to do it? Could I just add NaN in replacement or something?

Comment: Thanks for the help.